# Cmd cannot run my executable without providing ".exe"

Tags: c, windows, cmd, mingw-w64

So I have compiled & linked a program called "embed.exe" using mingw gcc compiler but it I am required by cmd to use "embed.exe" instead of "embed" to run it.

```
D:\c\embed\bin\release>embed
'embed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:\c\embed\bin\release>embed.exe  
Usage: embed [-h] <input>
```

I want to be able to run it by typing "embed" only. This only happens to my program. Yes, the pathext does contain .exe.
So this has made me think there's something wrong with mingw output, as if cmd doesn't recognize that it's an exe if I don't specify .exe.

Here are all my compiler flags:

```
-std=gnu11 -march=x86-64 -msse3 
-Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-braces 
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpedantic -Wno-format 
-flto 
-g -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG -Og 
-Wl,-subsystem,console
```

Comment: in `msys` prompt try `file embed.exe`

Comment: Using bash on windows: `file embed.exe` > `embed.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some weird characters in the extension? Such as something that just looks like `e` but not the ASCII `e`. Try renaming it.

Comment: It's all ASCII.

Comment: Can you post the command you link with? It looks like the file might be named `embed.exe.exe` from what you describe.

Comment: FYI, if you want to run a PE file named "embed" instead of "embed.exe", then add "." to `PATHEXT`. This works because trailing dots and spaces are stripped in the DOS namespace, so "embed." and "embed" are the same name.

Comment: @EugeneSh It happened to be a problem with bash on windows, not mingw, as I used bash on windows to create the bin directory.. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem is not with mingw but with how I create the `bin` directory. 
The problem occurs when I use **bash on windows** to mkdir the directory, but if I use windows' mkdir, it works. Who would've thought...

How to reproduce the error:

Directory:

```
embed
    |-->main.c
```

Cd to embed directory.

```
> gcc -c main.c -o main.o
> bash -c "mkdir bin"
> gcc -o bin/embed.exe main.o -Wl,-subsystem,console
> cd bin
> embed
'embed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Cd back and delete bin

```
> mkdir bin
> gcc -o bin/embed.exe main.o -Wl,-subsystem,console
> cd bin
> embed
Usage: embed [-h] <input>
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you compare the attributes of the directories created both ways?

Comment: @EugeneSh It's the same :/

Comment: CMD can't find "embed.EXE" based on the ".EXE" entry in `PATHEXT`. Normally the match works because the file system is case insensitive, but WSL defaults to creating case-sensitive NTFS directories. There's no file attribute for this. It's stuffed into an unused bit of the internal file record, so it's only accessible via `NtQueryInformationFile` : `FileCaseSensitiveInformation`, or from the Windows command line via `fsutil file querycasesensitiveinfo <path>`. Or in recent WSL builds it's an extended attribute accessible via `getfattr -n system.wsl_case_sensitive <path>`.

Comment: @eryksun wow thanks. Adding lowercase ".exe" to PATHEXT worked

Comment: @eryksun that comment would be a great answer!

Answer (score -1):

Read up on PATHEXT . . . it is an optional CMD environment variable that will help you here.

In fact, given a *.EXE file isn't working, I'm guessing you might already have that variable and it doesn't include EXE in the list.

Frank

Comment: I already have said in the question that I do have .exe in pathext. 
Also this only happens to my mingw compiled program. Not other programs I have installed.